# Page Controlled CollectionView

Tags: xcode

How to make a page controlled Collection View?
Let say i have a lot of 200 items in the collection view, how to limit the numbers of them per page 16 on 3.5" and 20 on 4" and to show next items on the next page. I want them to scroll Horizontal, i don`t like Scroll Direction option.

I managed to get all the items in the controller and to set the number of pages, but it doesnt scroll and i can`t limit them[image]